# When is the composition of harmonic functions harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have already proven that if $u(z)$ is harmonic and  $v(z)$ is analytic then $u(v(z))$ is harmonic, I'm guessing that if $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ are harmonic then $u(v(z))$ is harmonic if and only if $v(z)$ is analytic.

Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $u(z): A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $v(z): A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ functions such that:
$$
\nabla^2 u(z) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2}u(z) + \frac{\delta^2}{\delta y^2}u(z) = 0
$$
$$
\nabla^2 v(z) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2}v(z) + \frac{\delta^2}{\delta y^2}v(z) = 0
$$
We call these functions harmonic. Let us consider the composition $u(v(z))$, by definition this function will be harmonic if:
$$
\nabla^2 u(v(z)) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2}u(v(z)) + \frac{\delta^2}{\delta y^2}u(v(z)) = 0
$$

By the chain rule we have that:
$$
\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2}u(v(z)) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta [v(z)]^2}u(v(z)) \left( \frac{\delta}{\delta x} v(z) \right)^2 + \frac{\delta}{\delta v(z)} u(v(z)) \frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^2} v(z)
$$

$$
\frac{\delta^2}{\delta y^2}u(v(z)) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta [v(z)]^2}u(v(z)) \left( \frac{\delta}{\delta y} v(z) \right)^2 + \frac{\delta}{\delta v(z)} u(v(z)) \frac{\delta^2}{\delta y^2} v(z)
$$

Because $v(z)$ is harmonic we will have that:

$$
\nabla^2 u(v(z)) = \frac{\delta^2}{\delta [v(z)]^2}u(v(z)) \left[\left( \frac{\delta}{\delta x} v(z) \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\delta}{\delta y} v(z) \right)^2 \right]
$$

We can easily see that $\nabla^2 u(v(z)) = 0$ if $v(z) = 0$.

I'm not sure what to do if $v(z) \neq 0$ or if the conjecture is true.

Comment: A trivial counterexample is $u(z)=v(z)=\text{Re}(z)$